# Victory Chart control Y axis value intervals

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg, victory-charts, victory-native

I am trying to figure out a way to change the Y axis values intervals. Currently they are spread across $2000 interval because I have a min of $0 and max of $10500. Since the $0 is an outlier I want to squeeze the chart down so the points around $10000 show more. I want to change the Y axis to something like
[$0,$8000, $10000, $10500]. This would allow me to show more of the points on top then the outlier which looks ugly and you can't tell the minor differences on top. Here is the code below and also here is the array data which I highlighted the outlier:

[image]

[{"x": "20", "y": 10195.53}, {"x": "21", "y": 10181.26}, {"x": "22", "y": 10219.15}, {"x": "23", "y": 10182.75}, {"x": "24", "y": 10248.56}, {"x": "25",
"y": 10227.97}, {"x": "26", "y": 10273.36}, **{"x": "27", "y": 0}**, {"x": "28", "y": 10343.5}, {"x": "29", "y": 10224.12}, {"x": "30", "y": 10260.72}, {"x": "31
", "y": 10399.57}, {"x": "1", "y": 10330.53}, {"x": "2", "y": 10315.44}]

```
 <VictoryChart height={height} width={Dimensions.get("window").width}
              theme={VictoryTheme.material} 
              padding={{bottom: 30, right: 5, left: 5, top:5}}
              maxDomain={{y: Math.max(...arr.map(({y}) => (y + 1)))}}
              minDomain={{y: Math.min(...arr.map(({y}) => (y)))}}
>
  <VictoryAxis fixLabelOverlap tickLabelComponent={<VictoryLabel />}
               style={{
                 grid: {stroke: '#eaeaea', strokeWidth: 1, strokeDasharray: 4},
                 axis: {stroke: "#eaeaea", strokeWidth: 1},
                 ticks: {stroke: "#a1a1a1"},
                 tickLabels: {fill: "#a1a1a1", fontSize: 10},
               }}/>
  <VictoryAxis dependentAxis offsetX={Dimensions.get("window").width} fixLabelOverlap
               
               tickFormat={(t) => `${toCurrencyFormat(t, 0)}`}
               style={{
                 grid: {stroke: '#eaeaea', strokeWidth: 1, strokeDasharray: 4},
                 axis: {stroke: "transparent"},
                 ticks: {stroke: "transparent"},
                 tickLabels: {fill: "#a1a1a1", fontSize: 10},
               }}/>
  <Defs>
    <LinearGradient id="gradientStroke" x1="0" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <Stop offset="0%" stopColor={chartColor} stopOpacity={0.95}/>
      <Stop offset="100%" stopColor="#fff4dc" stopOpacity={0}/>
    </LinearGradient>
  </Defs>
  <VictoryArea
    style={{
      data: {stroke: chartColor, strokeWidth: 1, fill: 'url(#gradientStroke)', fillOpacity: 0.2},
      parent: {border: "2px solid #ccc"}
    }}
    data={arr}
  />

</VictoryChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually specify what tick values you want to show with `tickValues={tickValues}`, this overrides the automatic tick values:

https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-axis/#tickvalues